# PHP - Create array of HTML files from directory (Updated)

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, directory

**EDIT: I've simplified the folder structure to try to simplify the code, but I'm still not sure what to do.**

So, I'm attempting to build a portfolio blog using PHP and a rudimentary JavaScript for pagination, and I've run into a snag brought on because my understanding of PHP is pretty limited.  For the home page, I want to create some arrays that contains each post's title, content, post date, a summary, and a permalink; all of the files share the same base name (a YYYYMMDD format with either an .html or .php extension, depending on if it's the sections or the permalink).  The folders I have the post content in are set up like this:

```
articles
         |
         |
         title
             |
             YYYYMMDD.html
         |
         |
         summary
             |
             YYYYMMDD.html
         |
         |
         content
             |
             YYYYMMDD.html
         |
         |
         date
             |
             YYYYMMDD.html
blog
     |
     |
     YYYYMMDD.php
```

Herein lies the problem.  I'm not quite sure how to go about actually getting the files, or at the very least the names, out of each directory.  I've tried using scandir() and glob() but neither returned anything.

This is the code I have so far to declare the directories, get the files, and build the loop that creates each article.

```
<?php
$titleDirectory = '/articles/title/';
$dateDirectory = '/articles/date/';
$summaryDirectory = '/articles/summary/';
$contentDirectory = '/articles/content/';
$permalinkDirectory = '/blog/';

$title = scandir($titleDirectory, 1);
$date = scandir($dateDirectory, 1);
$summary = scandir($summaryDirectory, 1);
$content = scandir($contentDirectory, 1);
$permalink = scandir($permalinkDirectory, 1);

$postCount = count($permalink);

for ($post = 0; $post < $postCount; $post++) {
    echo "<article class='post'>";
    echo "<h3 class='postTitle'>" . file_get_contents($title[$post]) . "</h3>";
    echo "<div class='postBody'>" . file_get_contents($summary[$post]) . "</div>";
    echo "<a class='postLink' href='" . $permalink . "'>" . file_get_contents($date[$post]) . "</a>";
    echo "</article>";
}
?>
```

When I try to use this code, all it spits out is:

```
"; echo "
" . file_get_contents($title[$post]) . "
"; echo "
" . file_get_contents($summary[$post]) . "
"; echo "" . file_get_contents($date[$post]) . ""; echo ""; } ?>
```

Comment: What exact output are you aiming for?

Comment: I'm looking to use the arrays as a root for the file_get_contents() function to create each post on the index page with a loop.  Something akin to "for each item, print this as the title and this as the summary".

Comment: `When I try to use this code, all it spits out is:`...hm, that's just fragments of your php code. It looks like the php is not actually being executed. How precisely are you loading your script? It needs to be via a http request to a webserver such as Apache or IIS which has php installed and enabled

Comment: @ADyson After loading it onto the actual server, it just doesn't output anything.  The other PHP pages I have (the basic home page, without the article code) and the first blog post (which was made to test combining the parts of the post from external files) work fine, though.

Comment: If it's showing you PHP code in the page, then it's not executing that code (because normally you'd see the _output_ of the execution of the code, not the code itself). Does the script have a .php extension? If not, the webserver won't execute it as PHP. Did you load it via a browser using a proper URL e.g. `http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php`?

Comment: I did, yes.  The full link for testing it is `https://pandappuccino.rf.gd/GetPosts.php`, and the home page is `home.php` which works fine.  There's one file in each of the folders I'm trying to build arrays from, so it should output at least something, but I can't figure out why it isn't showing anything.

Comment: I just visited that link, and it isn't outputting _anything_. There are no fragments of PHP code visible, as you had stated in your question! Please ensure you are giving us an an accurate description of the situation.

Comment: Anyway, have you done any simple debugging? Put, for example `var_dump($permalink);` just after the `$permalink = scandir($permalinkDirectory, 1);` line, and tell us what it outputs. If it's an empty array, then there's simply nothing in that folder. If it shows `false` then, as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php, the specified directory doesn't exist (and you should also get a warning, which may be in your PHP log file, if that's enabled).

Comment: It turns out that the code didn't seem to like the format I wrote the directory in.  After removing the leading and trailing slashes (`articles/title` instead of `/articles/title/`) and using `var_dump`, the arrays work.  That has to be the stupidest syntax thing I've ever seen.

Comment: It's not a syntax thing. It's about relative paths. Have a read of https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the code working after some tinkering; since all of the components have the same file name but are in different directories, I just had to get one array (the name of the complete post).  Here's the code I used:

```
<?php
$directory = 'blog/';
$extension = '.php';

// Create array to store file names
$posts = array();

// Find files in directory
foreach( glob($directory . '*' . $extension) as $filename)
{
    $filename = basename($filename, $extension);
    $posts[] = $filename;
};

$posts = array_reverse($posts);
$postCount = count($posts) - 1;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $postCount; $i++) {
    echo '<h3 class="postTitle">';
    echo file_get_contents('articles/title/' . $posts[$i] . '.html');
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '<div class="postBody">';
    echo file_get_contents('articles/summary/' . $posts[$i] . '.html');
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<a class="postLink">' . file_get_contents('articles/date/' . $posts[$i] . '.html') . '</a>';
};
?>
```